# Alternative way of creating a list than a comprehension?

Tags: haskell

Currently I am doing something like this in my code:

```
--Generate a list of n 'Foo's
generateFoos n = [createFoo (show i) | i <- [1..n]]

-- Create a Foo with a given name
createFoo :: String -> Foo
```

I was wandering if there is a another way of doing this than creating a range `[1..n]` all the time...

Comment: Nothing at all, but just checking if there are other ways of doing things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say don't worry about it. "Creating the range `[1..n]`" isn't really going on here as a distinct step; that `[1..n]` desugars to `enumFromTo 1 n` and it's constructed lazily like everything else anyway. There's no hidden cost here one would need to eliminate.

Comment: Additionally, `[1..n]` can participate in list fusion, so the list may be eliminated entirely.

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on my comment above - the reason the `map` function arises naturally here is as follows.

In Haskell, list comprehensions are just syntactic sugar for do notation:

```
[ 2 * x | x <- [1..10] ]
```

is equivalent to

```
do { x <- [1..10]; return (2 * x) }
```

In turn, do notation is syntactic sugar for monadic binds - the above is equivalent to

```
[1..10] >>= \x -> return (2 * x)
```

This works because `List` is a monad. The code that makes `List` into a monad is (ignoring some irrelevant stuff)

```
instance Monad [] where  
    return x = [x]  
    xs >>= f = concat (map f xs)
```

so the call to `>>=` above is equivalent to

```
concat (map (\x -> return (2 * x)) [1..10])
```

which, if we replace the call to `bind`, is equivalent to

```
concat (map (\x -> [2 * x]) [1..10])
```

So we map the function `\x -> [2 * x]` over the list `[1..10]` and then call `concat` on the result. But since our function only every builds one element lists, we can skip out the call to concat and replace the code with

```
map (\x -> 2 * x) [1..10]
```

So it's natural that relatively simple list comprehensions can be turned into expressions that involve mapping a function over a range.

Comment: All list comprehensions can be converted to some combination of `map` and `filter` equally "naturally." The point of syntax sugar is that it is sweeter.

Comment: I agree - but I think it's helpful to know that there's no 'magic' going on with a list comprehension. It's transformed by the interpreter/compiler into plain old Haskell that you could write yourself. And simply *knowing* that you can transform your list comprehensions into different forms can sometimes help you to write more readable code. Similarly, knowing that there are alternatives to `do` notation helps you to keep the impure parts of your code isolated from the pure parts.

Comment: I'm only disagreeing with your allegation that map is more natural here. All your information is solid and I agree with your reasoning.

Comment: Ah ok. I agree. I'll change 'map syntax is natural' to 'map function arises naturally'

Answer (score 2):

I prefer it that way:

```
generateFoos n = map (createFoo . show) [1..n]
```

Or are the ranges itself the problem? Then I'd recommend:

```
generateFoos n = map (createFoo . show) (enumFromTo 1 n)
```

Comment: @drozzy: It's quite obvious. If you think `map` is evil, maybe Haskell is not the right language for you? :P

Comment: @NiklasB. `import Data.Humor`

Comment: @drozzy Haskell list comprehensions are syntactic sugar for the 'do'  notation; do notation is syntactic sugar for successive monadic binds (`>>=`); the bind function for lists does nothing more than `map` over the elements of the list. This is just getting you closer to the metal :)

Comment: Both of your versions are exactly equivalent to OP's version.

Comment: @n.m., indeed, with less syntactical sugar

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: Well, it's actually `flip concatMap`, where `concatMap = (concat .) . map`. :) -edit: and obviously I should scroll down first.

Comment: @drozzy One could argue it should be `Control.Humor`. :)

Answer (score 1):

No `map`, no range.

```
generateFoos n = unfoldr (doit (createFoo . show)) 1 where 
    doit f acc = if acc > n then Nothing else Just (f acc, acc + 1)
```

I do not guarantee any particular quality or property of this code though ;)

Comment: I love unfoldr. Seldom used, but powerful.